# Entity Framework Core 2.2.1 DbQuery error system.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to work with ***DbQuery***. I need to get non-entity type *UserDetailDTO* using raw sql. Added *DbQuery* to the context and call it from controller. But it's generate ***system.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException***.

My context:

```
public class TrainingAppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbQuery<UserDetailDTO> UserDetailDTO { get; set; }

    public TrainingAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<TrainingAppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }        
}
```

Controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly TrainingAppDbContext ct;

    public AccountController(TrainingAppDbContext ct)
    {
        this.ct = ct;
    }

    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var results = ct.UserDetailDTO.FromSql("SELECT * FROM users").ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I calling my UserDetailDTO from context it's generates an error.
[image: Error]

**I will be very grateful if you help!**

---

In DB rows had NULL values but model fields were not designed for these values.

Comment: What is the structure of the 'users' table is there a column 'Data'? Is it null for some rows? What is the structure of 'UserDetailDTO'?

Comment: there two solution. make the property in the modol nullable or remove nullable from the db. but the table and module propertytypes must have equal types. there is no workaround it. there is other library that dose not need those restriction as EntityWorker.Core. it work as good as Entityframe work i suggest to have a look at it